# Axler Linear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra

For question 2 from chapter 5A, it says that given ST = TS, prove that null $S$ is invariant over T. This was pretty straightforward by showing that $(S-\lambda I)Tv = T(Sv - \lambda v) = 0$ for $v \in \text{null} S$. In the next section he defined taking powers of operators $T^n$ for some $n$ non-negative integer. How would I show the same result for say null $S^2$ or $S^n$ for some arbitrary $n$ because the algebra seems weird. Would it just be trying to show that $(S - \lambda I)^nTv = 0$ as above? If it is the case then how do I even work with the power $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is exactly the same.

Let $x \in Null(S).$ Then $$ S(x)= 0$$ $$TS(x) =0$$  $$S(Tx)=0.$$

This shows that $Tx \in Null(S).$

Note that  $x \in Null(S)$ implies that $x \in Null(S^n)$ for any positive integer $n.$ Then

$$ S^n(x)= 0\\ T^nS^n(x) =0\\ S^n(T^nx)=0.$$ This proves the claim.

The following is also true. If, $(S - \lambda I)^nTv = 0,$ then $(S - \lambda I)^nTv = 0.$ This means The genereallised eigensapce of S is also T invariant.

This statement and the previous one are NOT the same things though. Based on your comment, I guess you wanted to prove the last one.

Comment: is this the same as showing that $null(S-\lambda I)^n$ is invariant under T for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$? The issue I had was manipulating $(S - \lambda I)^n$

Comment: No. I proved that $Null(S^n)$ is invariant under $T^n.$  What you have written in this comment is also true. It is true because  (S−λI)^n is a polynomial of S. Note that you can extend this like a binomial because  S and  λI commute.

Comment: yea I wasn't thorough enough. I wanted to show that $ker(S - \lambda I)^n$ is invariant under $T$. For case $n = 2$, it would just be if $x \in ker(S - \lambda I)^2$, then $(S - \lambda I)^2 Tx = (S^2Tx - 2STx + \lambda^2 Tx) = T(S^2x - 2Sx + \lambda^2 x) = T(Sx - \lambda x)^2$, so it is invariant under $T$.

Comment: Do th same thing for any n.

Comment: yeah thats what im gonna do next. I just stated the case for $n = 2$ so I can confirm from you if I did it correctly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One little comment I want to make here.  Nite that (A+B)^2 cannot be extended like a binomial unless we know that AB =BA. The good thing is that in our case S and scalar multiple of I commute.

Comment: actually isnt this part wrong? $(S^2x-2Sx+\lambda^2x) = (Sx-\lambda x)^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123300/discussion-between-derreckthomas-and-boka-peer).